# Is each card equally likely to be a Maverick?

Tags: keyforge

I have been reading a bit on deck composition and this question popped up in my head: can any card be a *maverick* or is it only few, "exciting" cards?

Obviously the maverick rate is minuscule compared to the deck combinations, so it's hard to say factually but is there a pattern to mavericks at all?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the low occurrence rates of mavericks it's impossible to state conclusively;
but, based on available data of registered decks, mavericks have a similar rarity curve to their non-maverick counterparts (8ishC:3U:1R:0S),
with the exception for some cards that specifically reference their own house (e.g. Wardrummer).

In total just over 4% of decks have at least a single maverick, and no decks have more than 3.

Comment: How do you check detailed stats like that?

Comment: theres a [public API](https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/?page=1&page_size=5&search=&power_level=0,2&chains=0,4&ordering=-date&links=cards) available to allow app integration, but with a little bit of hacky code you can churn through the decks and get statistics on occurrence rates.